# Eclipse sharing project option?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

I just opened my eclipse and was presented with following error:

```
SVN: '0x00000000: Open Project' operation finished with error: 0x00000000: Unable connect to 'my_project' project.
Please check that SVN meta-information exists and its format is supported by the current SVN plug-in version.
If so, it is possible that project working copy is relocated outside plug-in control.
At the current moment project will be automatically disconnected from source control.
0x00000000: Unable connect to 'my_project' project.
Please check that SVN meta-information exists and its format is supported by the current SVN plug-in version.
If so, it is possible that project working copy is relocated outside plug-in control.
At the current moment project will be automatically disconnected from source control.
```

I wanted to reconnect the project to SVN and I searched web and found the possible solution is to:

> right click on project - > team -> share project

And follow the prompts:

1. I had 2 options cvs ? svn ? -> I selected svn and clicked next.
2. select the repository location (use existing repository location). I selected one n clicked next.

However, in the 2 step, it says on the top:

> The wizard will help you to share your files with the SVN respository for the first time. Your project will automatically be imported into the SVN repository.

Has anyone tried this to reconnect to SVN repository? I am afraid that is does not starts checking in the project into the location and overwrite the code in repository.

I would only go with the sharing project option if someone is certain that this will not overwrite or check in anything into the repository but only reconnect it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same thing. On step 2, it should say:

> Project is already configured with SVN repository information.

It will not overwrite or check in anything in this case. Just reconnects.
Your case seems different since it says sharing for the first time. I think it may overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I upgraded Eclipse to Juno.
I used Tortoise to upgrade my working copy to SVN 1.7 and then used "Share Project..." in Eclipse and it worked for all my projects.